# Splitting a string by multiple possible delimiters

Tags: python, string, split, delimiter

I want to parse a `str` into a list of `float` values, however I want to be flexible regarding my delimiters. Specifically, I would like to be able to use any of these

```
s = '3.14; 42.2'  # delimiter is '; '
s = '3.14;42.2'   # delimiter is ';'
s = '3.14, 42.2'  # delimiter is ', '
s = '3.14,42.2'   # delimiter is ','
s = '3.14 42.2'   # delimiter is ' '
```

I thought about removing all spaces, but this would disable the last version; I tried the `re.split()`-function by doing `re.split('[;, ]', s)` which would work using a single character as delimiter but fails otherwise.

I can however do

```
s.replace('; ', ';').replace(', ', ';').replace(',', ';').replace(' ', ';')
s.split(';')
```

which works but seems not really like a good practice or useful - especially if I would add even more delimiters in the future. What would be a good approach to do this?

Comment: What if you wrote a function that took the delimiter as an argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use re.split and split on (The `[ ]` is a space and the brackets are for display only)

```
[;,] ?|[ ]
```

The pattern matches

- `[;,] ?` Match either `;` or `,` followed by an optional space
- `|` or
- `[ ]` Match a single space

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/B3CcbD/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/aS9dvH)

A bit more strict pattern with lookarounds could be asserting a digit on the left using lookarounds.

```
(?<=\d)(?:[;,] ?| )(?=\d)
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?<=\d)` Positive lookbehind, assert a digit to the left
- `(?:` Non capture group for the alternation

  - `[;,] ?` Match either `;` or `,` followed by an optional space
  - `|` Or
  - Match a space
- `)` Close non capture group
- `(?=\d)` Positive lookahead, assert a digit to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xDkoYU/1)

Example code

```
import re

strings = [
    "3.14; 42.2",
    "3.14;42.2",
    "3.14, 42.2",
    "3.14,42.2",
    "3.14 42.2"
]

for s in strings:
    print(re.split(r"[;,] ?| ", s))
```

Output

```
['3.14', '42.2']
['3.14', '42.2']
['3.14', '42.2']
['3.14', '42.2']
['3.14', '42.2']
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can account for the last space(s) like this:

```
re.split(r'[;,]\s*', s)
```

Here `\s*` will capture the spaces after the separator, if any.

Answer (score 0):

can also just do:

```
res = re.split('; |;|,|, | ', data)
```

see https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-split-multiple-characters-from-string/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you would know the delimiter of the input ahead of time, you could write a function that takes your delimiter as an argument, replaces with a space, and splits it:

```
def split_on_delim(strng, delim):
    return strng.replace(delim, ' ').split()
```

for example:

```
>>> s = '3.14; 42.2'
>>> split_on_delim(s, '; ')
['3.14', '42.2']
```